# Do search engines support microformats2?

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I just noticed that there was a new spec for microformats: [microformats2](http://microformats.org/wiki/microformats2). But I tried testing some HTML (the [example from here](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-entry)) in the Rich Snippets testing tool in Google Webmaster Tools and it says "no data detected".

Google's [help pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en) state they still support microformats, although schema.org microdata is preferred.

Has Google or any other search engine confirmed that they will or won't support microformats2?

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question. ;-) I have no idea, but I do know the site you liked to. I have used it before with some success. But I doubt if any of that was microformats2.

Comment: Related Meta discussion: [“Which search engines support …” questions?](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1105/17633)

Comment: @unor if it helps I really only care about Google and perhaps Bing.

Comment: @closetnoc perhaps, but I'm looking for confirmation either way, or even a strong indicator. I've yet to see any word at all from Google or Bing regarding mf2 (which has been around for at least a year).

Answer (score -2):

Google seems to be supporting microformats.
Google Webmasters Tool also contains option to analyze the Structured data.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/structured-data

It validates and list out the errors on micro formats as well.

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. I am asking about microformats **2** which is different to the original microformats spec (e.g. it uses `h-entry` not `hentry`).